# How to access member when calling on_member_update in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot that adds a specific role to a member once the member goes offline/invisible.

This is my code.

```
@ bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(before.status) == "online":
        if str(after.status) == "offline":
            guild = bot.get_guild(1234567890)
            role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'rolename', guild.roles)
            await member.add_roles(role)
```

Every time I run it, I get an error saying that member is not defined. How do I define member as the person who updated their status? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters `before` and `after` are both member objects, meaning that you can just use either for adding the roles:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(before.status) == "online":
        if str(after.status) == "offline":
            # also would be able to get the guild via after.guild or before.guild
            guild = bot.get_guild(1234567890)
            role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'rolename', guild.roles)
            await after.add_roles(role)
```

The parameters are simply;

- The `discord.Member` object prior to the update, i.e. `before`
- The `discord.Member` object after the update, i.e. `after`

---

**References:**

- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [`Member.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild) - The alternative to getting the guild that the member was updated in.
- [`on_member_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update) - The `Member` object is stated in the brackets below.

  [image]

Comment: I tried running your code, but got an error saying 'Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions' (even though I gave the bot admin permissions). How should I fix this?

The bot was able to add and remove roles when I called it on_message(message).

Comment: Make sure that the bot's highest role is above the role (in the role's list hierarchy) that you're trying to give the user.

Comment: No worries! Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer, because it might also help others facing the same issue! Good luck with the bot :^)